# Can I use postgres_fdw without foreign tables defined?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink, postgres-fdw

I have a production database "PRODdb1", with a read-only user account. I have a need to query(select statement) this database and insert the data into a secondary database named "RPTdb1". I originally planned to just create a temp table in PRODdb1 from my select, but permissions are the issue.

I've read abut dblink & postgres_fdw, but are either of these a solution for my issue? I wouldn't be creating foreign tables because my SELECT is joining many tables from PRODdb1, so I'm unfamiliar if postgres_fdw would still be an option for my use case.

Another option would be any means of getting the results of the SELECT to a .CSV file or something. My main blocker here is that I only have a read-only user to work with, but no way around that issue.

Comment: This Question might be more at home on the DBA Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no.  You can not use postgres_fdw without defining a foreign table in your RPTdb1.  This should not be much of an issue though, since it is quite easy to create the foreign tables.

I am in much the same boat as you.  We use a 3rd party product (based on Postgres 9.3) for our production database and the user roles we have are very restrictive (i.e. read-only access, no replication, no ability to create triggers/functions/tables/etc).

I believe that postgres_fdw has the functionality you are looking for, with one caveat.  Your local reporting server needs to be running PostgreSQL version 10 (or 9.6 at a minimum).  We currently use 9.3 on our local server and while simple queries work beautifully, anything more complicated takes forever, because the FDW in 9.3 tries to pull all data in the table before it is able to do JOINs or even use the WHERE statement.

version 9.6: Pushes down JOIN to the remote database before returning results.

version 10: Pushes down aggregates such as COUNT and SUM to the remote database before returning results.

(I am not sure which version adds the ability to push down WHERE statements to the remote DB, but I know it was not possible in 9.5).

We are in the process of upgrading our local server to version 10 this week.  I can try to keep you updated with our progress, feel free to do the same.